# Populate tags in post edit screen after Ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a project on WordPress project which needs to fetch some Movie data from IMDb.

The client wants an input field on Add/Edit Posts WP Back-end in which he will add IMDb URL and hit a button which will fetch out all the details of movie and then i have to save/put them in Custom fields and Taxonomies.

Now the problem i am able to fetch the details successfully but i need to save them to Taxonomies such as Post Tags. I want to load all star cast in Post Tags.
While he is in add/edit Post screen in WP Admin.

Any idea how to load those data into Tags. I am getting all the data from IMDb in JSON.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `tagBox.flushTags(el, a, f);` function. This function called by WordPress when you click the `Add` button.
Source: `\wp-admin\js\tags-box.js:L106`

Suppose you have an element which contain new tags then you can use in this way

```
<span id="myelem">tag1, tag2</span> //element which contain tags
tagBox.flushTags('.tagsdiv', '#myelem'); //.tagsdiv is fixed
```

But I don't think it is good idea. Seems like WordPress wrote it for its own use.

I will recommend another simple thing to add coma separated values in input box and then click `Add` button.

```
jQuery('#new-tag-post_tag').val('test, tag1, tag2').next('.button').click();
```